# xirr: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe with column Date, Cash, Name, KEY. I am trying to find the xirr by grouping the key. But when I run my code  get the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable"

```
f1['l'] = list(zip(f1["Date"], f1["Cash"]))
[![image][1]][1]

def xirr(transactions):
    years = [(ta[0] - transactions[0][0]).days / 365.0 for ta in transactions]
    residual = 1
    step = 0.05
    guess = 0.05
    epsilon = 0.0001
    limit = 10000
    while abs(residual) > epsilon and limit > 0:
        limit -= 1
        residual = 0.0
        for i, ta in enumerate(transactions):
            residual += ta[1] / pow(guess, years[i])
        if abs(residual) > epsilon:
            if residual > 0:
                guess += step
            else:
                guess -= step
                step /= 2.0
    return guess-1

print(xirr(f1['l'])) #till here it runs  
f2 = f1.groupby('KEY').apply(xirr(f1['l']))  # this line is giving error
```

Comment: The input to `apply` should be a function. Isn't `xirr(f1['1'])` a float?

Comment: f1[l] is an object . it have date (timestamp) and cash(float)

Comment: The input to `apply` should be a function. Maybe try `apply(xirr)`?

Comment: No its not working as I have to pass an argument ie f1[l] in xirr . if i dont pass it then it gives me keyerror:0